# Can a Bank supply its feeds directly instead of screen scraping? If yes ,where can I found documentation for it?

Tags: feed, yodlee, banking

As a newbie to Yodlee platform, I understand the basic concepts of Aggregation API .

Is there a way to plug in as a bank to supply direct data link instead of screen scraping to supply yodlee plaf and data model to be supplied to devs?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes a bank can feed obfuscated data, this is done by placing a middleware server between the core banking and the channel delivery switch.

Companies like Yodlee and Mint, et. al., rely on such a mechanism to provide access to their information partners.

Having said this, I'd be very surprised if any bank would provide you with direct access. Its a pretty cumbersome process even for the most reputed and well-intentioned of companies, individually, I doubt you will get direct access.